# Conditional string matching based on position in string (r)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to fill in some missing data in my dataframe. Some individuals did not have their sex entered, but it's encoded in their ID (second letter in ID). 
I'm finding using conditional pattern matching difficult since I only have a 1 letter "pattern" to look for. I need a way to say I only want if_else/grep to look for a matching pattern in the second element of the string (since it'll pick up matches in the first element)

Here's an extract of my data...

```r
stack <- tibble(ID = c("HM208", "MF009", "FF103", "FM003", "NF002", "NM003"), Sex= c("M", "F", NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

So I need to do something like (using dplyr) ...

```r
stack <- stack %>% mutate(Sex = if_else("contains M in second element", M, Sex ) %>% 
  mutate(Sex = if_else("contains F in second element", F, Sex )
```

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Hi there. Are you looking for `substr("abc", 2, 2)`?

Comment: That looks like it'll work! I haven't used substrings at all if r hence why I didn't know. I didn't notice this type of thing in the examples for pattern matching in dplyr/base

Answer (score 0):

```
stack %>% mutate(
  Sex = substr(ID, 2,2)
)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention but some ID's do not follow the code above e.g ID = "Z8" , "X6", but they all have their correct Sex given - an artefact of the protocol changing. Luckily the second string elements in these will always be a number. It means I need some kind of if_else statement, but I think I can manage it now I know about substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that accounts for the change in protocol. We assign a value to `Sex` based on whether the substring of `ID` is either M or F with `ifelse()`.

```
stack <- tibble(ID = c("HM208", "MF009", "FF103", "FM003", "NF002", "NM003"), Sex= c("M", "F", NA, NA, NA, NA))

library(dplyr)
stack %>% mutate(Sex = (ifelse(substr(ID,2,2) %in% c("M","F"),
                 substr(ID,2,2),Sex )))
```

...and the output.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  ID    Sex  
  <chr> <chr>
1 HM208 M    
2 MF009 F    
3 FF103 F    
4 FM003 M    
5 NF002 F    
6 NM003 M    
>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this! I went down the rabbit hole of regular expressions using grepl and found another way that I thought i'd share.                                                                                   
`stack <- stack %>% 
  mutate(Sex = case_when(grepl("^.M", ID) ~ "M", 
                             grepl("^.F", ID) ~"F",
                             TRUE ~ Sex))`